# How to change date format

Tags: javascript

I need to change date format to be dd-mm-YYYY HH:mm:ss. At the moment I am getting YYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss. Anyone can help me with this?

```
for (var course in data) {
        if (data[course]['days'] == value) {
            id[i] = data[course]['id'];
            name[i] = data[course]['name'] + " " + data[course]['startDate']['date'];
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function formatDate (input) {
  var datePart = input.match(/\d+/g),
  year = datePart[0].substring(2), // get only two digits
  month = datePart[1], day = datePart[2];
 return day+'/'+month+'/'+year;
}
alert(formatDate ('2010/01/18')); // "18/01/10"
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xUCf9/)**

Answer (score 2):

```
date = date.split('-'); //split and break into array
date = date[2] + '-' + date[1] + '-' + date[0]; //change the order you need
```

---

Update after OP Updated the question

```
date_parts = date.split(' '); //split and break into array get HH:mm:ss
date = date_parts[0].split('-');
date = date[2] + '-' + date[1] + '-' + date[0] + ' ' + date_parts[1]; //change the order you need
```